# WebSockets basics and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, websocket, phpwebsocket

I have been researching WebSockets for a few hours but can't seem to understand why you would need both client and server side libraries to help with WebSockets implementation?

I am using PHP so from research it seems like Ratchet is the most popular. But why would you need a server side implementation of WebSockets when server side HTML5 supports WebSockets? Can you build a chat system without the use of libraries at all? And can you build a chat system, for example, without any support on server-side, i.e. just with a jQuery library?

And how does WebSockets relate to node.js? I find it hard to get to grip with server side running JavaScript to send responses to a JavaScript front end.

Also, is this: https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/ library a similar thing to Ratchet?

Comment: html5 is client side only, not server side. Ratchet is needed to listen for the socket connections. On the client, you could just use the html implementation, but there are many different standards (multiple versions of the same standard) and you would likely need to implement more than 1. The library handles this for you.

Comment: Also, nodejs helps by taking the place of apache and php for processing on the server side. The nice thing about using nodejs (and socket.io specifically, but may be the same for others) is that the interface you use for the server side is the same as on the client side. So most functions/methods/objects you use on the server are the same as on the client. You don't need to learn two different libraries. It also handles stuff like heartbeats, re-connecting on disconnect, rooms, broadcasts and a bunch of other useful stuff.

Comment: Ahhh I see ok. I have just made an edit to this... but is  https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/ library a similar thing to Ratchet?

Comment: First line says: "**Quick hack** to implement websockets in php." It may work, but it is just a quick implementation. I haven't worked with ratchet (node.js/socket.io mostly), but I would assume that it is much more mature and handles a whole bunch more as well as being more user friendly. Also, just an FYI, both of those (and any php WS implementation) are not run through apache but as a standalone program started on the command line. Similar to nodejs which is also standalone.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! Appreciate it

Comment: Also, phpwebsocket doesn't appear to be maintained anymore. Last update was back in 2010 where as ratchet is (afaik) still actively developed.